# Datatables no ordena columna que se pasa por controlador, laravel 8

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-8

Estoy usando la librería de datatables y estoy tratando de que me pinte la tabla en orden ascendente de un campo específico pero no me lo está haciendo, lo raro es que reviso en laravel debugar y me esta haciendo la consulta que quiero pero no funciona. Realizo tal cual la consulta de mi bd de datos y funciona.

En si lo que estoy haciendo es utilizar arrastrar y soltar las filas para cambiarlas de posición y me esta funcionando, ya que revisó la base de datos y actualiza el campo order(posición) pero en la vista no lo hace.

Mi rutas `web.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('post',[PostController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
Route::post('post-sortable',[PostController::class, 'update']);
```

El controlador: `PostController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            //ordenar por order(position)
            $data = Post::orderBy('order','ASC')->get();

            return Datatables::of($data)

                    ->addIndexColumn()

                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
     
                           $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
                            return $btn;

                    })

                    ->rawColumns(['action'])

                    ->make(true);

        }

        return view('post');

    }

    //actualiza la posicion del campo order(position)
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            foreach ($request->order as $order) {
                if ($order['id'] == $post->id) {
                    $post->update(['order' => $order['position']]);
                }
            }
        }

        return response('Update Successfully.', 200);
    }
}
```

vista `post.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Create Drag and Droppable Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable in Laravel</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.0/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <h3 class="text-center mb-4">Drag and Drop Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable - Demo </h3>
            <table id="table" class="table table-bordered post-datatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="30px">id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>position</th>
                        {{-- <th>Created At</th> --}}
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tablecontents">
                  
                </tbody>
            </table>
          
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.0/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

      var table = $('.post-datatable').DataTable({

          "language": {
              "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
          },

          ajax: "{{ route('post.index')}}",
          columns: [{
                  data: 'id',
                  name: 'id'

              },
              {
                  data: 'title',
                  name: 'title'
              },
              {
                  data: 'order',
                  name: 'order'
              },

              {
                  data: 'action',
                  name: 'action',
                  orderable: false //se desabilita la ordenacion de la columna acciones

              },
          ],

          responsive: true,
          fixedHeader: true,
          select: true,

      });
      $("#tablecontents").sortable({
                items: "tr",
                cursor: 'move',
                opacity: 0.6,
                update: function() {
                    sendOrderToServer();
                }
            });

            function sendOrderToServer() {
                var order = [];
                var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                $('tr.row1').each(function(index, element) {
                    order.push({
                        id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                        position: index + 1
                    });
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "{{ url('post-sortable') }}",
                    data: {
                        order: order,
                        _token: token
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status == "success") {
                            console.log(response);
                        } else {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

cuando ejecuto la aplicacion me lo ordena por id de forma ascendente y no por el campo order(position)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecuto la consulta en el gestor de bd si lo hace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se en que estoy fallando, se les agradece sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuestas me la dieron unos colegas de unos grupos de wp y telegram.
Se debe ordenar en el frontend para que funcione:

despues de `columns` del script agregar el order(posición columna, orden)

```
 order:[[2,'asc']],
```